# populate a collection using mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know what could I do to correct the error to populate the collection User declared in the user.js file from the app.js

**user.js file**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require(bcrypt),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        index: { unique: true } 
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

**app.js file**

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/user');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vip');

var models = require('mongoose-models');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {


    var User = models.require('User')();


    var fluffy = new User({ name: 'Eduardo' });


    fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(User);
    });

    User.find(function (err, fluffy) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(User)
    })

});
```

the output error that MongoDB gives to me

C:\Users\edu\Dropbox\Node.js MongoDB\Mongoose>node app.js

```
assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: path must be a string
    at Module.require (module.js:362:3)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edu\Dropbox\Node.js MongoDB\Mongoose\models\user.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edu\Dropbox\Node.js MongoDB\Mongoose\app.js:2:1)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include details of the error you're experiencing? Is MongoDB actually running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of require(bcrypt) is incorrect. The require takes a String, so you need to put it inside a quote. It should be bcrypt = require('bcrypt')